# Node.js: page.click() does not work outside of page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to trigger a click event on a element but the click does not get triggered if i do not use it inside page.evaluate.

so, this works

```
await page.evaluate(async () => {
 $('#myExport').click();
});
```

but, this does not work

```
await page.click('#myExport')
```

I am new to Node.js and any help in

1) clarifying as to whats the difference between these two approaches

2) when should one be preferred over the other would be really great.

3) Why does click work inside page.evaluate and not the other way

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evaluate function will execute the `click()` function defined on your selector in the browser context. The `evaluate` works the same way as if someone opened the browser console and typed a command.

The puppeter `page.click()` function will move the mouse over the center of the selector provided and then perform the `mouse.down()` followed by the `mouse.up()` actions. Bear in mind that if it doesn't find a matching selector, the `page.click()` will throw an error, and if it has to scroll the page, it will trigger an navigation and thus it may have unexpected behavior.

You can solve the problem using the following code, I expect.

```js
await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(waitOptions),
  page.click(selector, clickOptions),
]);
```

Further information can be gathered on the api documentation:

[How the evaluation on puppeteer works](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args)

[How the page.click() works](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Are there any cases where 1 should be prefered over other approach?

Comment: When you use the page.click(), the behavior is more human-like, but it will be more performance costly, since you will use the node context to perform actions on the browser context. On the other hand, evaluating a click on the selector is less human-like and has a lower performance because you're actually running a command.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation

Comment: You chose based on if you need a more human-like behavior or if this is not actually a problem.